# How to add two number stored in char pointer?

Tags: c

In the below code i want to print the sum of 12 & 13 which i am passing as a string to char pointer.

How to get the desired result.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char *add(char *a, char *b)
{
char *s;
return s;
}

int main()
{
char *ptr;
ptr =  add("12", "23");
printf("add number %s\n", ptr);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the strings to integers using `atoi()` or `strtod()` and add them.

```
int i = atoi(a);
int j = atoi(b);

printf("%d\n",i+j);
```

Comment: Gopi@ In above code the return type of add function is char and and i am getting segmentation fault. I dnt know how to add two int value and store it in char pointer. Can you update the code so that i can get the output in my main function.

Comment: @AmitKumar You mean to say you can't change the prototype of the function? Why not print the value in the function only . What sense does it make to return a `char *`

Comment: Gopi@ Actually i have a requirement in which i have some integer value stored in a .txt file in a char buffer, from there i have to retrieve the value , add them and return o some other function.

Comment: @AmitKumar `int i = atoi(a), j = atoi(b); char buf[50], *s; sprintf(buf, "%d", i + j); s = strdup(buf); return s;` And `free(ptr)` from `main`, after its use.